# How to write header in armadillo csv file?

Tags: c++, csv, save, armadillo

Does anyone knows if there is a way to include a headers line in an armadillo csv file?

For example, if i want to save a matrix A, i can write:

```
arma::mat A; //variable declaration
A.zeros(10,2); // initialization to 0
A.save("A.csv",csv_ascii); // saving to "A.csv"
```

but how can a include into the csv file the following headers to indicate the content of each column?

```
"X" "Y"
```

thank you

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the [documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#save_load_mat), Armadillo can save directly to files or write to pre-opened streams. So the solution is to write the header manually to a file stream, then save the matrix to the stream:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <armadillo>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int main()
  {
  mat A(3,2,fill::randu);

  ofstream file("A.csv");

  file << "X,Y" << endl;
  A.save(file, csv_ascii);

  file.close();

  return 0;
  }
```